# Return Enum String Value using Enum Value as Index

Tags: typescript

I have the follow `enum` in TypeScript defined as such:

```
export enum Versions {
    AB1,
    AB2
}
```

I was wondering if there were a way to grab the value as a string by passing a value of the `enum` itself:

```
public version: Versions = Versions.AB1;

Versions[version]; // this is giving me 0, any way for it to return "AB1" ?
```

**Edit**

I have an object that uses this:

```
var body = {
   name: 'server',
   version: Versions[Versions.AB1] // this returns 0
};
```

Comment: By "this is giving me 0" do you mean `Versions[version]` and `Versions[Versions.AB1]` are 0 when you *compile and run* the code? That shouldn't be possible...

Answer (score 0):

> // this is giving me 0

Your code is [correct as is how enums work](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/enums.html):

```
enum Versions {
    AB1,
    AB2
}
const version: Versions = Versions.AB1;

console.log(Versions[version]); // 'AB1'
```

Your assumption is wrong.